# Can I omit non-public inheritance for forward-declaration of classes?

Tags: c++, inheritance, standards, forward-declaration, private-inheritance

Let's say I have a piece of code like this:

```
// Foo.h:
class Incomplete; // the forward-declaration
class Foo {
  void bar(Incomplete&); // doesn't really matter
};
```

```
// Foo.cpp:
class Incomplete : private Baz {
};
void Foo::bar(Incomplete&) {
}
```

Is forward-declaring classes like in `Foo.h` standard-compliant? If it is, since which language version? What about the same for `protected` inheritance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A forward declaration of a class is *required* to omit inheritance. You cannot write

```
class Incomplete : private Baz;
```

even if you wanted to.

The purpose of a forward declaration is to simply indicate that a particular name in a particular namespace refers to a class. Specifying the base class is part of the definition since it gives information about the class's layout in memory.